# Configure Automapper to map all strings for a given class the same way

Tags: .net-core, automapper

All the strings in the source object are comma delimited. I would like ot avoid code duplication and make Automapper treat all `string` property the same way.

I achieved it this way:

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, TargetClass>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.A, expression => expression.MapFrom(source => source.A.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.B, expression => expression.MapFrom(source => source.B.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.C, expression => expression.MapFrom(source => source.C.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.D, expression => expression.MapFrom(source => source.D.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)));
```

but as you see the code is copied few times. How to avoid it?

I tried that on the profile level for a single class, but don't know how to do it:

`ValueTransformers.Add<string>(val => val.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries));`
but it doesn't compile as `Split` returns `string[]`.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html

Comment: So it's an array. `CreateMap<string, string[]>().ConvertUsing(source => source.A.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries));`.

Comment: But then it works for all classes in the profile but in the title I just want it to apply to a single class.

Comment: That's painful and inefficient :) You can apply a value converter while filtering for source and destination types.